# Converting a Non-Numeric Date to Numeric Date in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, text

I'm trying to parse a text file that has the date at the beginning of the string. The string is delimited by a semicolon (`;`). The format of the string is a text string. Here's an example:

```
Thursday, June 01, 2017;8:02:45 PM;Automated
```

I'd like to use the date in a numeric format (`06/01/2017`) so I can work with the data better. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Remove semicolons and "Automated", then DateTime.Parse

Comment: And once you've got the date in a DateTime object then you can get the date as a string using date.ToShortDateString()

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
string date = "Thursday, June 01, 2017;8:02:45 PM;Automated";

Console.WriteLine($"({DateTime.Parse(date.Split(';')[0]).ToString().Split(' ')[0]})");
```

This returns the date like (6/1/2017).

What's in the `WriteLine` is all you really want though. I just included extra stuff to show it works.